# C#: SQL - One query at a time vs multiple query's in command text?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, .net

So, I find this a lot in my application. I usually need to run multiple queries, one after another when I call certain methods. I'm pretty sure I know the answer, but I wasn't 100% sure how benifical it would be.

I have a method like this, it just runs an SQL query, don't think beyond that.

```
using (var dbConnection = DatabaseManager.GetConnection())
{
    dbConnection.ExecuteQuery("lets pretend I've written a query here...");
    dbConnection.ExecuteQuery("lets pretend I've written a query here...");
    dbConnection.ExecuteQuery("lets pretend I've written a query here...");
}
```

Now, 3 querys, all on different tables so they couldnt be joined together. Do I really need to call this method 3 time? Or would it be benificial to seperate these querys with a `;` and just set the command text of all 3 querys to the `_command.CommandText`, or am I better to just run one at a time?

For people wondering, here is the ExecuteQuery method:

```
public void ExecuteQuery(string query)
{
    _command.CommandText = query;

    if (_parameters != null && _parameters.Count > 0)
    {
        _command.Parameters.AddRange(_parameters.ToArray());
    }

    try
    {
        _command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (MySqlException e)
    {
        Logger.Error(e, "Database error was logged.");
    }
    finally
    {
        _command.CommandText = string.Empty;
        _command.Parameters.Clear();

        if (_parameters != null && _parameters.Count > 0)
        {
            _parameters.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can run them as a single batch with multiple result sets.

Comment: [An example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/populating-a-dataset-from-a-dataadapter) using `DataAdapter`.  (can be done other ways) The `DataSet` will allow you to get to any of the result tables. [DataSet usage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ado-net-datasets)

Answer (score 0):

You can run the 3 at the same time. As you said, setting the CommandText with these 3 queries with the ; at the end of each one.

If you'll have not data return, there's no aditional work, but if you need to retrieve some data from the database, then you will need to use the method [NextResult](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.idatareader.nextresult(v=vs.110).aspx) of the ExecuteReader method.

I hope it been useful for you. Have a good code!